# Hide Class Library Enums from applications

Tags: vb.net, enums, class-library

I am using a Public Enum in a Class Library that is used within different classes within the library. I don't want it exposed to any applications that use the Class Library. I tried changing it to Private, but it says it has to reside within a Class to do that (which I can't do because it is used by many classes). How do I 'hide' it?

EDIT: Sorry about no code. Here's some code from the Class Library (I know it's vb, but I figure c# knowledge will be applicable?)

```
Public Enum HttpMethod
    [Get]
    Post
    Put
End Enum

Public Class WebClientProcessor
    Public Function HttpAction(netquery As String, method As HttpMethod, Optional json As String = Nothing) As WebClientResponse
    ' Stuff here
    End Function
End Class

Public Class Main
    Public Sub DoStuff
        Dim wcp As New WebClientProcessor
        wcr = wcp.HttpAction(StringOp.UrlCombine(_baseSiteURL, _licenseEndpointsMap(RequestType), LicenseKey), HttpMethod.Get)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Can you provide some code so we can have a more clear context ? Thanks

Comment: Use `internal`.

Comment: Can you explain these vague sentences: "*Hide Class Library Enums from applications*" as well as "*a Public Enum in a Class Library that is used within different classes within the library*" and "*don't want it exposed to any applications that use the Class Library*" and "*changing it (what? type or instance?) to Private*", for example with some code, please?

Comment: It's `Friend` in vb.net. `Friend Enum HttpMethod ... End Enum`.

Comment: Don't put your solution in the question. If you don't need an answer tot he question then delete the question, otherwise add an answer with the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually solved it by removing the "Public" just to read:

```
Enum HttpMethod
    [Get]
    Post
    Put
End Enum
```

Comment: I thought that enumerations became public by default if it wasn't explicitly stated. Is it getting treated as Internal\Friend instead?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `internal` modifier.

> Internal types or members are accessible only within files in the same assembly.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/internal

Comment: And this is a perfect example of why you don't spam tags. Now there's an answer that was perfectly legitimate based on the tags but is actually irrelevant to the actual question.